# How do you recognize that $|\zeta(s)|$ has ridges, where $\zeta(s)$ is the Riemann Zeta function?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, graphing-functions

Let $s=\sigma+it$ the complex variable, thus our notation will be $\Re s=\sigma$ and $\Im s=t$.

MathWorld article for the [Riemann Zeta Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannZetaFunction.html) refers that $$|\zeta(s)|$$
has "ridges" for $0<\sigma<1$ and I understand that then for $t>0$, and shows us with a plot those for $0<\Im s<100$.

> **Question.** Can you tell us if one can detect easily (
>   how do you recognize, and if it's possible with easy calculations, I say in a cheap manner) that for $0<\Re s<1$, there exists real numbers $a<b$ such that  $|\zeta(s)|$ has a ridge here $a<\Im s<b$. **Many thanks.**

Thus I am asking for an explicit example $1<a<\Im s<b<100$, that is if it's possible an explicit example of $a$ and $b$ showing how detect the ridge with mathematics. You are welcome if you want add yourself graphics, to illustrate your explanation.

Comment: This is at the beginning of any complex analysis course : If $f(z)$ is analytic and non-constant, and $z= a$ is a local extremum of [$|f(z)|$ then $f(a) = 0$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_modulus_principle) (this is obvious from the Taylor expansion $f(z) = f(a)+ C (z-a)^n + o(|z-a|^n)$).

Comment: Also $|\frac{\zeta(s)}{s}-\frac{1}{s-1}|$ shows some sort of waves parallel to the $x$ axis, as any (convergent) Laplace transform.